# how to strip domain from hostname in bash

Tags: bash

How do I strip domain from hostname in pure Bash?

Example:

```
hostname = myserver.site.mydomain.com
output=${hostname#*.*}
```

will give

```
site.mydomain.com
```

while

```
hostname = myserver.site.mydomain.com
output=${hostname%*.*}
```

will give

```
myserver.site.mydomain
```

I want only "myserver"

Any ideas?

I wish to use pure Bash, not sed, awk, cut, etc.

Comment: Too many splats.  Hint:  If you are stripping from the right(%) the asterisk goes on the right, stripping from the left (#) the asterisk goes on the left.  You can only strip from left *or* right using this particular mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
hostname=myserver.site.mydomain.com
output=${hostname%%.*}
```

%% should remove longest match from tail.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

[Parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) would be usefull

```
$ hostname=myserver.site.mydomain.com
$ echo ${hostname/.*/}
myserver
```

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename    expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern
>   against its value is replaced with string.

Comment: What about getting the complete hostname with subdomains. example myserver.site